# Install Rails Fails nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I cannot install rails for some reason : Im not sure why nokogiri-1.7.1 fails here is the error log

```
  [2017-04-11 13:44:55] local.WARNING: Error while running Command gem update --system && gem install rails —no-rdoc —no-ri && gem install bundler  
    [2017-04-11 13:44:55] local.ERROR: Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
    Successfully installed i18n-0.8.1
    Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.6
    Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.3
    Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.0.5
    Successfully installed activesupport-5.0.2
    Successfully installed rack-2.0.1
    Successfully installed rack-test-0.6.3
    Successfully installed mini_portile2-2.1.0
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/ext/nokogiri
    /usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170411-1620-c4v4vi.rb extconf.rb
    mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

    extconf failed, exit code 1

    Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.7.1/gem_make.out
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (URI::InvalidURIError)
        URI must be ascii only "?gems=\u{2014}no-rdoc"
```

I have tried the other various fixes that say to install these packages :

utoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm3 libgdbm-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev

Nothing seems to work

Comment: Do you have ruby-dev? 
`sudo apt-get install rubyX.X-dev` where X.X is version ie `sudo apt-get install ruby2.2-dev`

Comment: I added ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev to make it work